# Javascript performance question

Tags: javascript, performance, dom

I'm so curious because I'm maintaining a 3d engine written in Javascript.

1. Which is faster, `parseInt(el.style.width)` or `el.offsetWidth`?
2. Should I write `parseInt(el.offsetWidth)`?
3. Which is faster, `getElementById()` or `childNodes[]`?
4. Which is faster, `new Image()` or `appendChild('img')`?
5. Give me please a link to a splendid Javascript PERFORMANCE guide

Thank you!

Comment: My suggestion: Benchmark it yourself. Intuitively, I'd guess that el.offsetWidth is faster (because it doesn't require traversing the entire css ruleset like el.style.width does), and that childNodes[] is faster (because it doesn't require traversing the entire dom like getElementbyId does). But I don't really know, which is why I'm putting this as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @Ben - `getElementbyId` doesn't traverse the DOM. It is an in memory lookup of the element. As such is extremely fast.

Comment: Agreed with Ben, benchmark it. AFAIK el.offsetWidth is subject to be calculated at runtime. You should probably trade off some memory and cache all results. Also, i'd suggest to use canvas, because DOM is slow and memory hungry.

Comment: @patrick dw - In theory yes. IE doesn't agree with you though. :) See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got quite a bit of confusion here.

> **1.** *Which is faster, parseInt(el.style.width) or el.offsetWidth?*

- `el.style.width` gives you the width set by javascript or style attribute in the markup.
- `offsetWidth` gives you the current width of the element (including borders).

> **2.** *Should I write `parseInt(el.offsetWidth)`?*

No, `offsetWidth` returns a number. But  you should specify the radix whenever you use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)!

> **3.** *Which is faster, `getElementById()` or `childNodes[]?`*

If you got the parent use the `childNodes`. If you got the id, you can use byId. Performance will depend on the browser ([test](http://jsperf.com/childnodes-getbyid)).

> **4.** *Which is faster, `new Image()` or `appendChild('img')`?*

If you want to force the browser to download a resource, use `new Image()`. If you want to add an image to the layout use `appendChild(IMAGE_ELEMENT)`

> **5.** *Give me please a link to a splendid Javascript PERFORMANCE guide*

I rather leave you with this link: http://jsperf.com/, and let you do A/B testing.

Comment: @Hello71 - A/B testing is an experiment approach for making marketing decisions, when there are two alternatives and a single variable. In this context it refers to the methodology of deciding between two pieces of code in terms of performance.

Comment: Nice answer +1. Interesting about IE and `...ById()`. Do you happen to know if it is actually traversing the DOM to get find the element? I'd be curious about its performance on a complex HTML structure. I've just always assumed it would be quick. I'll probably do some testing later on.

Comment: @patrick dw - I've updated the test at http://jsperf.com/childnodes-getbyid. Now it's 1000+ elements and 3 levels deep. The results are actually worse. *getById* is 50x slower on IE 6-7. I have no idea as to why it happens. Suprised me too, but It probably isn't just a lookup in IE. With 10000+ elements it becomes 500x difference. Seems like O(n) to me.

Comment: @glambalazs - Thanks for the updated jsperf! I sure was wrong to assume. That's insane, and really good information to know while IE6/IE7 still have a share of the market. I'm usually pretty good about caching so I don't overdo DOM selection, but sometimes I loosen up a bit when selecting by ID. Now I know better. Thanks again!

Comment: Your answer really helped me. Special thanks for link to jsperf.com

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of sites regarding Javascript preformance.

Really old site..but provides some insight.

http://home.earthlink.net/~kendrasg/info/js_opt/jsOptMain.html

Reference to a book

http://oreilly.com/server-administration/excerpts/even-faster-websites/writing-efficient-javascript.html